# Passing Data from App Engine to Compute Engine

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions, google-compute-engine

I have built an full stack MERN app and deployed it with App Engine. The app uploads data to a google Cloud Storage bucket where an AI program running on a Compute Engine analyzes the files and places them in another Storage bucket. I am using Cloud Functions to trigger a command on the Compute Engine when the bucket is updated, but I'm lost on how to connect to the Compute Engine in the Cloud Function. The AI program is a Python program. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simplest solution**
Make the GCE instance have a public IP and from Cloud Functions make a *request to you instance*. You can protect the GCE endpoint by this solution by adding a [Identity-Aware Proxy on the port](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding) that is exposing the remote execution service. And add the Cloud Function service account to the list of accepted users.

**Suggested soltuion**
In order to send data to Compute Engine from Cloud Functions internally you need to create a `connection` between the Cloud Function and the VPC network that holds the instance.

You will find the instructions on how to do this on [Connecting to a VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/connecting-vpc).

Then, once the Cloud Function has access to the VPC network, you have *to make a request* using the instance private IP.

---

When I say *to make a request* I mean that you need service on you GCE instance that is listening to request E.g: a flask application and executes the command on the request.

Comment: thanks for the direction! I'll reply with more after I follow this trail. Many thanks

Comment: Sure, no problem

Comment: I ended up using a Cloud Function triggered by Cloud Storage to start the GCE. It's working great, except for running a startup script that I set on the GCE's metadata. The startup script isn't running.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62096826/startup-script-in-metadata-not-running-python-google-compute-engine-cloud-sto

Comment: Can you check out my incomplete solution and offer anything? @Juancki